# Как работать с QSqlDatabase пример ( QSqlDatabase example)

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt, qsqldatabase

Заголовок изменён потому, что ответ на вопрос отражает почти все аспекты работы с QSqlDatabase для того чтобы сделать запрос к бд.

Есть [метод](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html):
`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QSqlDriver *driver, const QString &connectionName)` - сигнатура из подсказки qt (на картинке) в [доке](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html) немного другая.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что если я создаю базу без указания `connectionName` (как на рисунке выше), то `query.exec`:

- возвращает `код работы 1`,
- в противном случае (если я задаю имя данному соединению) возвращает `код работы 0`, да еще и выдает ошибку на этапе исполнения

> "QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open"

Получается, что я не могу задать имя подключению и соответственно удалить потом подключение, чтобы создать новое, тоже не могу.

Проблема именно в имени подключения, почему при его указании, не работает `query.exec()`?

***PS***: сам по себе запрос нормальный, я проверял на `pgadmin`, более того он работает, если ***не указывать*** имя подключения.

```
бд postgre\
Qt 5.15.3 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release 

build; by GCC 11.3.0) on "xcb" 

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS [linux version 5.15.0-56-generic]
```

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlResult>
#include <QSqlRecord>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSqlDatabase testDb;
    testDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");//testDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL","qwe");
    testDb.setHostName(some_ip);  
    testDb.setPort(port);
    testDb.setDatabaseName(name);
    testDb.setUserName(some_user);
    testDb.setPassword(some_pass);
    bool ok = testDb.open();
    std :: cout <<"\n----------------------\nconnection  to gid  DataBase is "<<ok;
    QSqlQuery query;


    query.prepare(some_select);
    int a = query.exec();
    QSqlError err = query.lastError();
    //вывести ошибку
    std :: cout <<"\n query.exec status (0 if bad) = "<<a<<"\n";
//  query.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я разобрался:

- объект базы данных `QSqlDatabase testDb("QPSQL","NAME1")` надо создавать перед подключением к ней. Не делайте его глобальным каким-то или вне функции. Важно, чтобы он находился в  отдельной области видимости и "исчезал" перед удалением(т.к. область видимости завершается).
- Создание объекта `QSqlDatabase testDb` и заполнение его `HostName` и остальных полей должно быть внутри отдельной области видимости. Внутри неё же надо создавать и exec-ать query запрос.
- При создании `QSqlQuery query` использовать конструктор и передать туда бд `QSqlQuery query(testDb)`.
- Удалять бд нужно вне этой области видимости `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("NAME1");`
- Не забыть написать `query.finish();`

```
void func(QString queryString)
{

    {
        QSqlDatabase testDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL","NAME1");//set db driver for PostgreSQL
        testDB.setHostName("127.0.0.1"); //ip in string as "127.0.0.1"
        testDB.setPort(5432); // port in int
        testDB.setDatabaseName("my_db");//string
        testDB.setUserName("my_name");//string
        testDB.setPassword("qwerty12345");//pass in string
        bool ok = testDB.open();
        std :: cout << "testDB opened = " << ok << "\n";

        QSqlQuery query(testDB);
        int a = query.exec(queryString);
        query.finish();
        //----------------
        QSqlError err = query.lastError();
        std :: cout <<"\n query.exec of calc is done status (0 if bad) = "<<a<<"\n";
        std :: cout << "\nERROR IS "<<err.text().toStdString();
        
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("NAME1");
}
```

Это самый локаничный и правильный пример по использованию QSqlDatabase, он позволит вам делать даже несколько подключений и с ними нормально работать.